# Get row in a qtablewidget from a qpoint object in pyqt4

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4

Suppose I have a `QTableWidget` in pyqt4 and a `QPoint` object. How can I get the row in my table which corresponds to the coordinates in my `QPoint` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [QTableView::rowAt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtableview.html#rowAt) function.

```
row = table.rowAt(point.y())
```

Comment: Ok, so if `p` is my `QPoint` I use can do something like `print self.mytable.rowAt(p.y())`, thanks!